# Is it possible to check if a user has a twitter account in the built-in twitter app of iOS 5?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, twitter

iOS 5 has deep twitter integration. How can I check if the user has an account in the built-in twitter app (meaning he uses it), and then do a `UIApplication openURL:` to trigger following a user or pre-composing a tweet?

> One of the new features for developers in the iOS 5 SDK is support for
>   the Twitter API. Apple has made it easy for developers to add Twitter
>   support to their apps and to allow users to easily control whether or
>   not an app has access to post to their Twitter account.

According to [this site](http://mashable.com/2011/10/12/twitter-ios-5-integration/) it is possible. How's that Twitter Framework called?

Comment: -1 Five seconds in Google [will answer this question.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Tweeting/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011191)

Comment: In his defence, he's also asking about launching the Twitter app so the user can follow an account.

Comment: @dontWatchMyProfile Actually, I didn't know the answer. I'm not even an iOS developer. If I found it, so can you. And that's what the downvote button is for.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
- (void)tweetButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
     Class tweetComposer = NSClassFromString(@"TWTweetComposeViewController");

     if( tweetComposer != nil ) {   

         if( [TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet] ) {
            TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetViewController = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];

            [tweetViewController setInitialText:@"This is a test."];  // set your initial text

            tweetViewController.completionHandler = ^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result) {
                if( result == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultDone ) 
                {
                    // user is done with composing
                } 
                else if( result == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultCancelled ) 
                {
                    // user has cancelled composing
                }
                [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
            };

            [self presentViewController:tweetViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
        } 
        else {
             // The user has no account setup
        }
    }   
    else {
        // no Twitter integration
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For the first part of your question...

```
ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[[ACAccountStore alloc] init] autorelease];
ACAccountType *twitterAccountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
NSArray *twitterAccounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:twitterAccountType];
```

This is how we're doing it in [DETweetComposeViewController](https://github.com/doubleencore/DETweetComposeViewController).

Comment: I have used your twitter library and it is really cool. Although I have a couple of questions that I want to ask.
1) Can we retrieve the user's screen name?
2) Can we implement login, logout functionality?

Comment: 1) You can retrieve the user's Twitter screen name on iOS 5 using Apple's ACAccount framework. See our DETweetAccountSelectorViewController class.  2) You can not "log out" of iOS 5 Twitter procedurally (you're not really logged in from the app's perspective). The user has to go to the Settings app to do this. However, if you're implementing iOS 4-style tweeting, you have full control over logging in and out. See the OAuth routines.

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like:

```
BOOL didOpenTwitterApp = [UIApplication openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"twitter:///user?screen_name=senior"]];
```

This will return false if the app can't open the official Twitter app.

If you just want to create a new Tweet, use the [native API](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Tweeting/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011191)